# User Form - VLOOKUP and Form Calculation

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

I have a form with several fields. I have a field on the form where I would like a calculation to take place. This requires a `VLOOKUP` of a helper column function.

In a regular cell I can type the following:

`=VLOOKUP(B3&C3&D3,Ins_Price_Tbl,5,0)`

Ins_Price_Tbl is a data table.

And get the answer I am looking for.

My form has the Text Boxes

```
txtAdjustmentCountYearA - An integer
txtInsurance - A String
txtAdjustmentYearA - A year like 2018
txtAdjustmentCostYearA - The result field
```

I need `txtAdjustmentCostYearA` to perform the `VLOOKUP` where in this case C3 would just equal "Adjustment" or whatever text I type in and multiply it by the `txtAdjustmentCountYearA.Value`

So I would potentially have something like:

`txtAdjustmentCountYearA.Value` being equal to 2

`txtAdjustmentYearA.Value` being equal to 2018

`txtAdjustmentCostYearA` being equal to something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(Me.txtInsurance.Value&"Whatever I type in here"&Me.txtAdjustmentYearA,Ins_Price_Tbl,5,0) * txtAdjustmentCountYearA.Value
```

Comment: Added a solution to your post via `Application.VLookup` and taking into account that textboxes always are strings.

Answer (score 1):

**As close as possible to your OP**

```
Option Explicit                             ' declaration head of code module

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet                         ' provide for range reference
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet") ' <~~ change to your sheet name
Dim searched As String, found As Variant, factor As Double
searched = Me.txtInsurance.Text & ws.Range("C3").value & Me.txtAdjustmentYearA.Text
' use the Application function VLookup instead of worksheetfunction.VLookup
' allowing to ask a IsError condition (variable found has to be of type Variant!)
  found = Application.VLookup(searched, ws.Range("Ins_Price_Tbl"), 5, 0)
' Textbox values are always strings and have to be converted (e.g. to Double)
  If IsNumeric(txtAdjustmentCountYearA.Text) Then factor = CDbl(txtAdjustmentCountYearA.Text)
' Check possible errors before assigning result to textbox (again as String!)
  If Not IsNumeric(found) Or IsError(found) Then
     Me.txtAdjustmentCostYearA.Text = "Nothing found"
  Else
     Me.txtAdjustmentCostYearA.Text = found * factor
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would appreciate some response. - Did you find my answer helpful so that you can mark it as accepted?